# pressing event in UIButton?

Tags: iphone

when i am pressing my UIButton ,(**i did not release my mouse button**),i want to change
title? i tried touchupinside through  XIB.but it was called after i released my mouse button.
i tried both land also all states....?
[sButton setTitle:@"hai" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sButton setTitle:@"hai" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Comment: If you initialize your button like this:
[sButton setTitle:@"Normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sButton setTitle:@"Pressed" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
doesn't it work ok?

Answer (score 1):

The [Control Events](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events) documentation will list all of the events you can subscribe to for controls (in this case, your `UIButton`). The one you want is `UIControlEventTouchDown`. But the problem with your requirement is that pushing the button covers the screen with the user's finger and I wonder whether changing the title will really be beneficial.

Comment: its like combo box ,with big width